# need solution to pull url of keyword search from search engine in windows forms application using C#

Tags: c#, regex, winforms-to-web

I'm creating an windows forms application in C#. I want to put a feature where user can get a url from different search engines based on keywords they provide. I'm facing the problem of how to grab the url from a search engine. I have tried regular expression but didn't work. I even tried this code but its not working as its opening the website in the browser. the code is:

```
string a;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    a=textBox1.Text;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www."+a+".com"); 
}
```

please help me out as other than this i'm unable to complete my college project

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking here. Are you wanting the user to input a keyword such as `"google"` and return `"http://www.google.com"` ? What do you want to do with the link after you have it?

Comment: I want to provide the user to have numbers of links from where they can get their desired answer based upon what keyword user is providing...

Comment: it will also show the total numbers of links are present over internet.

Comment: like if user search "rent in mumbai" then he can get all the possible links who provide hotel services in mumbai.

Comment: the phrase `rent in mumbai` returns 15,300,000 results on google, returning all of those results would be difficult I think.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make WebRequest, which will return html. Then you need to find those links in html
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

To make search in google just build url like this:
https://www.google.pl/#q=search+string

I really don't know search engines policity, but you need to read it first, becouse making somethink like this could be illigal

**I found that google doesn't allow this so it will be illegal!**

Comment: Yes, that is illegal. Google doesn't allow this!
Maybe other search engines will

Comment: It isn't illegal. It's just against the terms of service.

Comment: It's against the TOS to web scrape google like this, but you could just sign up for a custom search account and query the google API https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview